# Inconsistent code highlighting on the iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app, syntax-highlighting, code, code-block

I've noticed a few posts with code blocks that aren't getting any syntax highlighting when they should.

[This Q&A](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/86357/52050) for example has no highlighting:

> [image]

Whereas [this Q&A](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85349/52050) does:

> [image]

The strange thing is, the first post is tagged with [a tag that does have highlighting enabled](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/indesign-scripting/info) and the second isn't; so on the site we have the opposite behaviour.

Initially I though it had something to do with the tags, but it seems inconsistent even within tags that have highlighting enabled.

From what I can tell, *all* posts on SO and other programming related sites are always highlighted, but on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) it's rather inconsistent and I can't figure out why.

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)